# How can i do this list addition in java?

Tags: java, list, iteration, addition

I have two lists where i iterate through one list and try to match some items and then replace the contents of one list with another.

```
public static void setLtItems(List<ItmResponse> list1, List<ItmResponse> list2){
        ListIterator<ItmResponse> list1Iterator = list1.listIterator();
        while (list1Iterator.hasNext()) {
            ItmResponse a= list1Iterator.next();
            for (ItmResponse b : list2) {
                if (a.getOrgTransNo().equalsIgnoreCase(b.getOrgTransNo())) {
                // replace the item in list1 with the list2 item
                list1Iterator.set(b);
                }
            }
```

The above code is working fine but if list 2 has one more item which matches with an item in list1 which is not added to list1 because list1 contains only 1 item and list has 2 items which matches with the list1 item. So after replacing the 1st item of list2 in list1 i have to add the second item of list 2 to list1 as a second item. How to do this in java?

Comment: so first time you use `set` and then after that use `add` ?

Comment: Ya but `while (list1Iterator.hasNext())` will have only one element. Thats is the problem.

Comment: see my answer, if I understand you correctly this should work

Answer (score 1):

try

```
while (list1Iterator.hasNext()) {
    boolean found = false;                 // new
    ItmResponse a= list1Iterator.next();
    for (ItmResponse b : list2) {
    if (a.getOrgTransNo().equalsIgnoreCase(b.getOrgTransNo())) {
       // replace the item in list1 with the list2 item

       if (!found) {
           list1Iterator.set(b); 
           found = true;
       } 
       else {
           list1Iterator.add(b); 
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort the list1and list2 using the OrgTransNo will work

Ad if the values contains in list1 add to list1 without set ...

Comment: If your list is not sorted how can you assume that the list2 second element is same as the list2 first element.